# Problem with Typo3 creating a lot of apache2 processes

Tags: apache, typo3, typo3-9.x

We're running Typo3 in production and we sometimes have issues with our typo3 server not responding for no apparent reasons.

The issue seems to be linked to typo3 creating a lot of apache2 processes that uses all the server ressources and ultimately lead to the server not responding.

Exemple of a top command with many apache2 processes :
[image: apache2 processes]

I found a similar issue on typo3 forum : https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80804
But solutions here did not help us to solve the issue.
We trid to remove the locks files, but only thing that seems to work is to restart typo3 untill it finally gets to a stable state again.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Typo3 version : 9.5.22
OS version : Red Hat 4.8.5-44

Comment: Are you using php-fpm? Do you have error log messages, either apache or TYPO3 (for TYPO3: e.g. var/log on Composer or typo3temp/var/log). Can you write more about your setup? For the problem with the lock files - depends on your storage - are you on an nfs system? What do you mean by "restart typo3"? Restart the webserver?

Comment: (I am sorry I cannot help your right now but more information in the question might be helpful!)

Comment: It looks like something is blocked - is your system waiting for something? As described in the issue you can use strace to try to get more info about your state. You can also use strace for multiple processes, e.g. see https://www.caichinger.com/blog/2016/02/09/strace_multiple_processes/

Comment: IF you are affected by the flock problem, you can use other locking mechanism like https://github.com/b13/distributed-locks (but would only switch if that is really the problem).

Comment: I had once strange server configuration like that: `pm = static
pm.max_children = 1`. So there was only one php-fpm fork and the fpm mode was static. When TYPO3 do 404 it makes separate HTTP request to server. But since there was only one fork and it was static it could not respond to this request so it was like apache was hanging. So my advise - try to figure out if its because of 404 OR maybe you doing some internal request during main request and this are endlessly nested.